# Why is it so bad to have large partitions in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have seen this warning everywhere but cannot find any detailed explanation on this topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For starters

> The maximum number of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition is
>   2 billion.

If you allow a partition to grow unbounded you will eventually hit this limitation.

Outside that theoretical limit, there are practical limitations tied to the impacts large partitions have on the JVM and read times. These practical limitations are constantly increasing from version to version. This practical limitation is not fixed but variable with data model, query patterns, heap size, and configurations which makes it hard to be give a straight answer on whats too large.

As of 2.1 and early 3.0 releases, the primary cost on reads and compactions comes from deserializing the index which marks a row every `column_index_size_in_kb`. You can increase the `key_cache_size_in_mb` for reads to prevent unnecessary deserialization but that reduces heap space and fills old gen. You can increase the column index size but it will increase worst case IO costs on reads. Theres also many different settings for CMS and G1 to tune the impact of a huge spike in object allocations when reading these big partitions. There are active efforts on improving this so in the future it might no longer be the bottleneck.

Repairs also only go down to (in best case scenario) the partition level. So if say you are constantly appending to a partition, and a hash of that partition on 2 nodes are compared at not an exact time (distributed system essentially guarantees this), the entire partition must be streamed over to ensure consistency. Incremental repairs can reduce impact of this, but your still streaming massive amounts of data and fluctuating disk significantly which will then need to be compacted together unnecessarily.

You can probably keep adding onto this of corner cases and scenarios that have issues. Many times large partitions are *possible* to read, but the tuning and corner cases involved in them are not really worth it, better to just design data model to be friendly with how Cassandra expects it. I would recommend targeting 100mb but you can go far beyond that comfortably. Into the Gbs and you will need to start consider tuning for it (depending on data model, use case etc).

Comment: Wow, awesome answer!  I'm starring this one so I can forward it on to some of the devs here.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Thanks for your detailed response! I’m a Cassandra novice so could you confirm my understanding of your response? The main reasons are: 1) having large partitions is inefficient in the caching layers. 2) large partitions are inefficient for replicating data between nodes. Does that sound right?

Comment: Thats a good abbreviated version yes. I would add that the JVM is inherently bad at large objects.