# Maximum number of columns does Cassandra support in a table

Tags: database-design, cassandra, time-series

I'm able to design a table to store a single time series data.

`CREATE TABLE timeseries( partition bitint, timestamps bigint, key text, value text, PRIMARY KEY((partition,key),timestamps);`

Partition is a function (eg: divide) of timestamps itself.
This will store a single value at a time for a key.

What if we need to store some 1000 values against a key at a time. There will be value_1, value_2,...value_1000. ie, 1000 more fields in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries(partition bitint,timestamps bigint, key text, value_1 text,value_2 text,value_3 text,
 . . .

value_999 text,

value_1000 text,

 PRIMARY KEY((partition,key),timestamps);
```

Does cassandra table have a limitation in number of fields it supports? Is there any better way for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you should do `PRIMARY KEY((partition,key), timestamps, value_id);` where value_id goes 1-1000 and a single `value` text. Then you will be able to have 1000 values without huge rows within your partition. Issue is that the entire row is considered a single unit when paging. The smallest unit being 1000 values makes it impossible to break up and do in smaller chunks. The JVM has a hard time allocating large contiguous blocks for the sending which puts a huge load on the old gen space and long GC pauses.

There is also the total size of the partition to consider. While the cell limit to a partition is 2 billion there are some practical limits described in [Why is it so bad to have large partitions in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272571/why-is-it-so-bad-to-have-large-partitions-in-cassandra/46273617#46273617).

Comment: PRIMARY KEY((partition,key), value_id, timestamps); will take same size like what you mentioned and provides query with time range also.right?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra has a hard limit of 2 bilion cells per partition. Most likely you will get into trouble before reaching that "hard" number.

In order to calculate the number of cells in a partition you could use the following formula:

```
nv = nr(nc - npk - ns) + ns
```

where:

- nv = number of cells in the partition
- nr = number of rows
- ns = the number of static columns
- nc = number of columns
- npk = number of primary key columns

`nc - npk - ns` is also known as number of values per row.

Some more [Cassandra limitations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html).